# JQuery - Placing a Google Map in a "content" isn't visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

Having a bit of trouble placing a map within data-role="content" while using Google Maps v3 and JQuery. No errors show in the console so I am having a hard time debugging. No map shows up on the screen.

Here are my two files:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=true"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mapload.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="map">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**mapload.js**

```
function initialize()
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(49,-8),
    zoom: 15,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816645/jquery-mobile-and-google-map-not-visible) gave me some insight but didn't complete answer my question.

---

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={REPLACE THE BRACKETS AND THIS TEXT WITH YOUR API KEY}&sensor=true"></script>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pageinit', '#index',function(e,data){    
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(11.618044,-34.823347),
            zoom: 15,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
    });
    </script>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" id="content" style="padding:0;position:absolute;top:40px;right:0;bottom:40px;left:0;">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%"></div>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's only one available way of using Google maps with **`jQuery Mobile`**. Because **`jQuery Mobile`** is specific window load can't be used to initialize the map.

Specifically correct height is needed to initialize the map successfully and it can ONLY be done during the **`jQuery Mobile`**  **`pageshow`** page event. If you want to find out more about jQuery Mobile page events and why is **`pageshow`** event important for plugin initialization take a look at my private blog **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**. Or you can find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)**.

Let me make this story short, here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/pkZHg/

And here's a javascript and CSS used:

#### Javascript

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index',function(e,data){    
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.618044,-87.823347),
        zoom: 15,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
});
```

### CSS

```
#content {
    padding: 0;
    position : absolute !important; 
    top : 40px !important;  
    right : 0; 
    bottom : 40px !important;  
    left : 0 !important;     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

load mapload.js at the end of the html

```
<div data-role="page" id="map">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mapload.js"></script>
```

the DOM is not ready yet when you are calling the map functions

the other error might be CSS styling.. you could try this

a set width and height
`

```
#map-canvas {
  width: 480px;
  height: 640px;
}
```

`

Comment: well that was one error. the other is make sure ur map-canvas css is correct.. inspect the body and see if there is any actual content inside map-canvas they u can figure out how to best CSS with your webpage. 
that should do the work